# Compare tuple values in Two lists

Tags: python-2.7

```
**for i in range(a):
    p=int(raw_input("Enter Elements in List1:"))
    list1.append(p)
    d1=defaultdict(int)
    for item in list1:
        d1[item]+=1
print list1
print d1.items()
print ""**
```

How to compare tuple values in the following list output?
Here my answer should return the tuple values (207,2), (208,1) and (209,1) because those are same in both the lists.

```
input1 : [203, 203, 204, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 207, 209]

output1: [(203, 2), (204, 2), (205, 1), (206, 1), (207, 2), (208, 1), (209, 1)]

input2:  [204, 203, 205, 205, 206, 206, 207, 207, 208, 209, 205, 206, 205]

output2: [(203, 1), (204, 1), (205, 4), (206, 3), (207, 2), (208, 1), (209, 1)]
```

Comment: You should use markdown for code. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown

Comment: @JavierCastellanos you should edit the code if the questioner fails to do so...

Comment: @JonKiparsky I don't have enough reputation to edit questions.

Comment: Now I have edited my code and output. Here the entire code is not mentioned because what I am really interested is to compare the tuple value

Comment: Do you want to compare the tuples, or do you want to compare the counts? That is, are you interested in solving the problem of comparing output1 to output2, or are you interested in comparing input1 to input2? (in either case, I think the ouput you want is the same: tuples showing (value, count) where count for value is the same in both lists)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Counter`

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> lst = [203, 203, 204, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 207, 209]
>>> freqs = Counter(lst)
>>> freqs
Counter({203: 2, 204: 2, 207: 2, 205: 1, 206: 1, 208: 1, 209: 1})
>>> lst2 = [204, 203, 205, 205, 206, 206, 207, 207, 208, 209, 205, 206, 205]
>>> Counter(lst2)
Counter({205: 4, 206: 3, 207: 2, 203: 1, 204: 1, 208: 1, 209: 1})
```

First compare method:

```
>>> [ k  for k,v in Counter(lst2).iteritems() if v == Counter(lst)[k] ]
[207, 208, 209]
```

Second compare method:

```
>>> for k,v in Counter(lst2).iteritems():
...     if v == Counter(lst)[k]:
...             print k
... 
207
208
209
```

Comment: I want to compare the tuple values which is in my output1 and output2. Whenever the count value for the value field are same in both the output list, the program should return those values..In these case, it should return 207, 208, 209

Comment: In your code is it possible to compare the dictionary values in both of the list?..values which have same count should return their values